# How do I UPDATE a value only WHERE COUNT(subquery using GROUP BY)=1?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to set a row value to 1 when it is the only row in a group, with a single query.

Current Table (CATEGORY_BRAND):

```
|categoryId | brandId | featured |
|-----------+---------+----------|
| 1         | 100     | -1       |
| 1         | 101     | -1       |
| 1         | 102     | -1       |
| 2         | 100     | -1       |
| 3         | 110     | -1       |
| 3         | 111     | -1       |
| 4         | 102     | -1       |
| 5         | 101     | -1       |
| 6         | 100     | -1       |
| 6         | 110     | -1       |
| ...       | ...     | ...      |
```

Hoped for Result (CATEGORY_BRAND):

```
|categoryId | brandId | featured |
|-----------+---------+----------|
| 1         | 100     | -1       |
| 1         | 101     | -1       |
| 1         | 102     | -1       |
| 2         | 100     | 1        |
| 3         | 110     | -1       |
| 3         | 111     | -1       |
| 4         | 102     | 1        |
| 5         | 101     | 1        |
| 6         | 100     | -1       |
| 6         | 110     | -1       |
| ...       | ...     | ...      |
```

(My sincerest apologies if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anyone else doing an UPDATE like this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the most performant, but should work (although you should test it first).

```
UPDATE category_brand JOIN (
    SELECT categoryId
    FROM category_brand
    GROUP BY categoryId
    HAVING COUNT(categoryId) = 1)
  AS single_cbs USING(categoryId) SET category_brand.featured = 1;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. I've gone through and checked the rows in the database manually, and this does exactly what I'm looking for. :D

Comment: Good stuff. As seen by the other answers, you can't reference the table you are modifying in a subquery. Hence `JOIN` to the rescue.